# Tracking down cuda kernel register usage

Tags: c, optimization, cuda

I am trying to track down register usage and came across an interesting scenario. Consider the following source:

```
#define OL 20
#define NHS 10

__global__ void loop_test( float ** out, const float ** in,int3 gdims,int stride){

        const int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        const int idy = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
        const int idz = blockIdx.z*blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

        const int index = stride*gdims.y*idz + idy*stride + idx;
        int i = 0,j =0;
        float sum =0.f;
        float tmp;
        float lf;
        float u2, tW;

        u2 = 1.0;
        tW = 2.0;

        float herm[NHS];

        for(j=0; j < OL; ++j){
                for(i = 0; i < NHS; ++i){
                        herm[i] += in[j][index];
                }
        }

        for(j=0; j<OL; ++j){
                for(i=0;i<NHS; ++i){
                        tmp = sum + herm[i]*in[j][index];
                        sum = tmp;
                }
                out[j][index] = sum;
                sum =0.f;
        }

}
```

**As a side note on the source** - the running sum I could do +=, but was playing with how changing that effects register usage (seems it doesn't - just adds an extra mov instruction).
 Additionally this  source is oriented for accessing memory mapped to 3D space.

Counting out the registers it would seem there are 22 registers ( I believe a float[N] takes up N+1 registers - please correct me if I'm wronge) based on the declarations.

However compiling with:

```
nvcc -cubin -arch=sm_20 -Xptxas="-v" src/looptest.cu
```

yields:

```
0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 25 registers, 72 bytes cmem[0]
```

Ok so the number is different that what is 'expected'. Additionally if compiled with :

```
nvcc -cubin -arch=sm_13 -Xptxas="-v" src/looptest.cu
```

The register usage is *far*  less - 8 to be exact ( apparently due to stronger adherence in sm_20 than sm_13 to IEEE floating point math standards?):

```
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z9loop_testPPfPPKfS2_4int3i' for 'sm_13'
ptxas info    : Used 17 registers, 40+16 bytes smem, 8 bytes cmem[1]
```

As a final note, change the macro OL to 40, and suddenly:

```
0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 28 registers, 72 bytes cmem[0]
```

In conclusion I would like to know where registers are being eaten up, and what results in the couple observations I have made.

I don't have enough experience with assembly to get through a cuobjdump - the answer certainly lies buried in there - maybe someone can enlighten me about what I should be looking for or show me a guide as to how to approach the assembly dump.

Comment: Could it be that your loops were unrolled by the compiler for OL with value 20 and did not unroll for 40?

Comment: I would think Ashwin's comment is correct.  Also you should consider flattening your looping sums via warp level addition cases, as outlined in the CUDA C Programming guide.
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf

Comment: I am pretty confident that the difference in register count will have nothing to do with floating point, or loop unrolling or anything else mentioned so far. Remember that sm_20 is internally a 64 bit architecture and sm_13 is a 32 bit architecture. This means pointers have twice the register footprint compiled for sm_20 compared with sm_12.

Comment: despite that pointers are twice as wide they should still count as a single register should they not? Also I believe the loop is unrolled as the number range is known at compile time and there will be no divergence - but I'll have to test that theorywith `#pragma unroll` and see if they're different.

Comment: 64-bit pointers (or any 64-bit values) require 2 registers each since registers are 32 bits.  But @talonmies, doesn't the pointer size depend on whether `-m32` or -m64` is specified?  I can't remember which is the default; probably defaults to match the present operating system.

Comment: There are other reasons for this, but in general sm_20 requires higher register usage than sm_1x.  sm_20 is a **pure** load-store architecture, for one, while sm_1x has some non-load-store instructions that can use memory (shared memory, e.g.) as an operand. Why not use cuobjdump on both binaries to see the actual machine code produced -- then you can see for yourself what is happening.

Comment: Actually, I remembered the main reason register count goes up on sm_20 devices (no address registers), which I decided is probably the answer to this question, so I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

sm_20 and sm_13 are very different architectures, with very different instruction set (ISA) design. The main difference that causes the increase in register usage that you see is that sm_1x has special-purpose address registers, while sm_2x and later do not. Instead, addresses are stored in general-purpose registers just like values are, which means most programs require more registers on sm_2x than on sm_1x.

sm_20 also has twice the register file size of sm_13, to compensate for this affect.

Answer (score 0):

Register usage does not necessarily have a close correlation to the number of variables.

The compiler tries to assess the speed benefit of keeping a variable in a register between two points of use in the code by comparing the potential gain in a single kernel with the cost to all concurrently running kernels due to there being less registers available in the register pool. (A Fermi SM has 32768 registers). So, it's not surprising if changing your code causes unexpected fluctuations in the number of registers used.

You really should only be worried about register usage if the profiler says that your occupancy is limited by register usage. In that case, you can use the `--maxrregcount` setting to lower the number of registers used by a single kernel to see if it improves overall execution speed.

To help reduce the number of registers used by a kernel, you can try to keep variable use as local as possible. For instance, if you do:

```
set variable 1
set variable 2
use variable 1
use variable 2
```

That may cause 2 registers to be used. While, if you:

```
set variable 1
use variable 1
set variable 2
use variable 2
```

That might cause 1 register to be used.

Comment: Hmmm, the compiler will probably treat both of your examples as if they were both the second one.

Comment: How would the compiler be able to use only one register in the first example?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Do you know what that extra "r" stands for?

Comment: Not sure, but I think it might be "real" (as in float). This is to differentiate from other types of registers, such as address registers, which don't exist on NVIDIA GPUs after sm_13.